# Differences and recommended methods to override JavaFX TableCell

Tags: javafx, java-8, tablecell, tablecolumn

So... I was trying javafx.
I tried to change some content of UI (TableView in this case), but sometimes I was a little bit confused...

If we have this **sample code**:

```
public <S, T> TableCell<S, T> getTableCellFactory(BiFunction<T, TableCell, Node> content) {
    return new TableCell<S, T>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText(null);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            setGraphic(null);

            if (item != null && !empty && getTableRow() != null) {
                setGraphic(content.apply(item, this));
            }
        }
    };
}

public static final <S, T extends Object> TableColumn<S, T> getTWColumn(
        final String title, final double width,
        Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<S, T>, ObservableValue<T>> cellValueFactory,
        Callback<TableColumn<S, T>, TableCell<S, T>> cellFactory) {

    TableColumn clm = new TableColumn<>(title);
    clm.setCellValueFactory(cellValueFactory);
    if (cellFactory != null) {
        clm.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
    }
    clm.setPrefWidth(width);

    return clm;
}

public ObservableList<TableColumn<T, ?>> getTableColumns() {
    return FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            getTWColumn("columnTitle", 500.0,
                    (TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<T, T> p) -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue()),
                    (TableColumn<T, T> p) -> new FXContent().<T, T>getT_TableCellFactory()
            )
    );
}
```

What are the loading and execution differences between 1, 2 and 3?

***1 - (TableColumn p) -> FXContent.getT_TableCellFactory()***

```
public abstract class FXContent {

    public static <S, T> TableCell<S, T> getT_TableCellFactory() {
        return getTableCellFactory((item, tc) -> {
            Text t = getBaseText(item.getSome1());
            t.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(tc.getTableColumn().widthProperty());

            return getBaseRightLayout(t);
        });
    }
}
```

***2 - (TableColumn p) -> new FXContent().getT_TableCellFactory()***

```
public final class FXContent {

    public FXContent() {}

    public <S, T> TableCell<S, T> getT_TableCellFactory() {
        return getTableCellFactory((item, tc) -> {
            Text t = getBaseText(item.getSome1());
            t.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(tc.getTableColumn().widthProperty());

            return getBaseRightLayout(t);
        });
    }
}
```

***3 - implemented (TableColumn p) -> this.getT_TableCellFactory()***

```
public Interface FXContent {

    default <S, T> TableCell<S, T> getT_TableCellFactory() {
        return getTableCellFactory((item, tc) -> {
            Text t = getBaseText(item.getSome1());
            t.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(tc.getTableColumn().widthProperty());

            return getBaseRightLayout(t);
        });
    }
}
```

**Regards.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to 1) The class loader has to first find and load the class, if it hasn't been cached, before invoking the method.

Number 2) also requires the class loader to do its thing, after which an object is created/instantiated, and only then is the method invoked.

The 3rd option just invokes the method.

Comment: Thanks.
... and execution ?

Comment: Execution is the last step in all three which is the invoking of the method. Since all three methods have identical code there is no difference.